# Creating a data frame using a single line code

Tags: r

I need to select data for 3 variables and place them in a new data frame using a single line of code. The data frame I'm pulling from is Dance, the 3 variables are Lindy, Blues and Contra.

I have this:

```
Dance$new<-subset(Dance$Type==Lindy, Dance$Type==Blues, Dance$Type==Contra)
```

Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1/ ?subset and ?data.frame are required to understand the basics
2/ the $ symbol is for retrieving a column from a data.frame
3/ Paste your data using `dput` so this is a reproducible example

Comment: I think you want something like: `newDance <- subset(Dance, Type %in% c("Lindy","Blues","Contra"))`, which is also equivalent to `newDance <- Dance[Dance$Type %in% c("Lindy","Blues","Contra"),]`

Comment: You're trying to assign a subset of the rows in your data frame to a vector and the lengths also don't match up. Did you mean `Dance.new = ...`

Comment: Adding to @thelatemail's comment, your method would work if you separate with `|` (the "OR" operator), rather than commas: `Dance[Dance$Type==Lindy | Dance$Type==Blues | Dance$Type==Contra, ]`, but thelatemail's method is more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can do this, but I'd forget the subset part

```
danceNew <- Dance[Dance$Type=="Lindy"|Dance$Type=="Blues"|Dance$Type=="Contra",]
```

If you only want specific columns

```
danceNew <- Dance[Dance$Type=="Lindy"|Dance$Type=="Blues"|Dance$Type=="Contra",c("Col1", "Col2")]
```

Alternatively

```
danceNew <- Dance[Dance$Type %in% c("Blues", "Contra", "Lindy"),]
```

Again, if you only want specific columns do the same. The advantage with the final options is you can pass the values in as a variable, thereby making it more dynamic, e.g

```
danceNames <- c("Lindy", "Blues", "Contra")
danceNew <- Dance[Dance$Type %in% danceNames,]
```

Answer (score 0):

you're mixing up the variables and the dataframes

this should do the trick..
if your initial dataframe is called "Dance" and the new dataframe is called "Dance.new":

```
Dance.new <- subset(Dance, Dance$Type=="Lindy" & Dance$Type=="Blues" & Dance$Type=="Contra"); row.names(Dance.new) <- NULL
```

I like using "row.names(Dance.new) <- NULL" line so I won't have the useless column of "row.names" in the new dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone. This is what ended up working for me.

```
dancenew<-subset(Dance, Type=="Lindy" | Type== "Blues" | Type=="Contra")
```